# Slider gallery in jQuery (no plugins)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slider preview (3 pages). Each page is `80vw` large and the box has `overflow-x: hidden`. 
I'm able to slide each page by clicking on a bullet whit this code

```
  function slideIntro (){

   var slideLeft = $(this).data('slide'),
      slidePerc = '-' + slideLeft + '%';

    $('.pallino').removeClass('pallino-attivo');
    $(this).toggleClass('pallino-attivo');
    $('.page-slide-wrap').css('margin-left', slidePerc);
 }
```

The problem is that I'd love to make it scroll on `.mouseout()` every 4 seconds what I tried to do is calculate each case and write the code but I'm sure that there is a shorter solution than this

```
function slideShow1 (){

$('.pallino').removeClass('pallino-attivo');
$('.page-slide-wrap').css('margin-left', '-100%');
$('.pallino').slice(1,2).addClass('pallino-attivo');

}

function slideShow2 (){

$('.pallino').removeClass('pallino-attivo');
$('.page-slide-wrap').css('margin-left', '-200%');
$('.pallino').last().addClass('pallino-attivo');

}

function slideShow3 (){

$('.pallino').removeClass('pallino-attivo');
$('.page-slide-wrap').css('margin-left', '0%');
$('.pallino').first().addClass('pallino-attivo');

}

function slideShow (){

setTimeout(slideShow1, 4000);
setTimeout(slideShow2, 8000);
setTimeout(slideShow3, 12000);

}
```

What I would like to do is add a rule able to stops the function when the mouse is over the gallery box `.page-slide-wrap` and cycle the whole function.

I forgot to say that the slides now move using `margin-left` as you can see in bot codes

**PLEASE FEEL FREE TO TELL ME IF I AM NOT CLEAR ENOUGH**

Comment: I found this that i can adapt to my needs http://jsfiddle.net/6FF4y/4/ . I'm still trying to understand how to stop the slide when the mouse is over

Comment: to stop slides you need to store `setTimeout`'s as variables so you can call `clearTimeout` ... and then again have another `restart()`

Comment: Thank you! How can I combine this whit the mouse out stop?

Comment: need 2 event handlers to do it